# Can't find onclick function definition in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress site in which I need to make a change in the onclick function _filter_page. I have tried to search through the entire directory but can't find a function with that name. I guess it's worth mentioning since it's from a Wordpress theme I didn't create everything myself from scratch. How can I find where it's defined?

I tried to search if it's a default javascript/jquery/Wordpress function but couldn't find anything their either. I'm happy to provide more information but I'm not sure what to share.

It's also worth mentioning that the onclick function works as expected. I just want to make some improvements.

```
<div class="ajax-search-pagenav pagination-md">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="_filter_page(1)" class="page-link bg-primary">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="_filter_page(2)" class="page-link" rel="nofollow">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="_filter_page(2)" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right nomargin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can say that the function you specified is not among the WordPress internal functions. Could you check if this function is in the theme files, probably because it's theme customization? I think it is usually in .js files, but there is a possibility that it can be defined inline in .php files as well.

There are applications to search for files in some directory. Using one of them, you can find which file contains `_filter_page.`

The explanations you mentioned are not enough to help you.

Comment: Good to know that it's not a Wordpress function. I have searched through the entire directory using "String Locator" but can only find where the function is being called, not where it is defined. Any other ideas?

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea. Pagination may have been added later with plugins. Or some themes offer their own plugins and can add with these plugins as well. I don't know if you should have found it when you searched the directory. If it is not defined, the function should not work anyway.

When you click these buttons, I think it sends a request. You can check which "action" your request is using from the developer console and search for the theme and plugins with the action name there.